# Anchor tags in Stack Overflow Documentation Markdown

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I've tested using anchor tags, but they don't seem to be supported given the current subset of HTML that Stack Overflow supports (if there is a way, please let me know!)

I recently was editing some documentation and wanted to link to Python's in place `sort()` method. I looked for it in the documentation, and found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/209/list/2035/list-methods-and-supported-operators#t=201608020040320618721). Now, I could simply link to that and let whoever clicks that link find it with Ctrl-F or something, but it seems like it would be much cleaner to be able to link directly the method that I'm referencing. There are many other documentation examples that are as long or longer than that one (Like Java's 'Array' section) that also would benefit from these anchor tags.

Can anchor tags be added to the supported markdown in Stack Overflow, or even just Documentation? They could either be done through HTML, as part of something like headers, or through their own special syntax.

I feel that this merits a new discussion on top of the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894), as Documentation is far more likely to be long and cumbersome than a answer to a single distinct problem, and thus having anchors would greatly benefit navigating between different sections of documentation.

Comment: Anchor tags definitely work, you have two of them in your question.

Comment: I'm referring to anchor tags to anchor to a specific part of a question or example, not the example itself - so that the example writer can have an anchor to a part of the example that can be referred to directly rather than needing to refer to the example as a whole.